# WSO2 APIM vs WSO2 EI 6.6, 7.0 and DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Can somebody please explain, how WSO deploy its products?

First i got familiar with WSO EI 6.6. I could create a proxy service or use the DSS to make API alternative to entity framework in .net core services.

Then I found out that the superior product to WSO2 EI is WSO2 APIM - api manager.

WSO2 APIM has WSO2 IS included, so it is basically the single point for authentication and service proxying and so on.. However I have not seen there any option to make the DSS ??

WSO EI 7.0 is completly different to WSO EI 6.6 as far as i understand. WSO EI 7 is the name for 3 other products balerina integrator, microservice and streaming integrator. None of these services has the /carbon framework and all of them are just some apis for some custom editor. If this is true, why do they call it WSO EI 7?? Does that mean that the configuration of proxy services or access to database through res api is obsole and should not be used for new project?

So basically there is no way to have DSS in latests products?? Do I must use WSO EI 6.6 in order to use the DSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have scratched my head at the naming and grouping of these products previously as well. From what I could figure, every now and then the groups change. As you have noticed rightfully, EI was the latest one to change. It indeed split into 3 entities. It is however still usable with code from EI 6.6. The Micro Integrator can be downloaded separately and used with all the code and CAR files made with 6.6. I have run a couple of them and found no problems thus far. It is basically the latest version but without the Carbon framework and frontend. One MI instance also runs just 1 CAR file but does so really fast.

As for your DSS needs I have no experience with that side of WSO2. I googled however and found that DSS can be downloaded [right here](https://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/) as a standalone product. I hope that solves your last question.

The APIM is not superior to EI either, but functions in a different way. Since the older products were all based on Carbon as you mentioned before means there was a certain bit of overlap. IS for example can also be downloaded separately.

If I was to guess I would say they WSO2 will be trying to make all their services into Microservice versions in the upcoming years. This is just speculation btw.

If you want to dive more into the reasoning behind WSO EI 7.0 and why it was decided to work like that I would suggest [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRF97aCQxyc) by the WSO2 director.